# Объясните, как работают for и foreach, для чего они нужны?

Tags: c#, foreach, for

Начал самообучение C#.
Никак не пойму, для чего нужны ***for***, *foreach* (точнее, вроде как понимаю, но не совсем). Покажите наглядный пример для чего они нужны, понятный даже для того кто не учит яп.

Comment: Ну попробуй без них. Понадобятся - поймёшь.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

С нуля так с нуля. Значит пойдем с самого начала.

Для начала разберемся с циклом `for`

Возьмем самый простой пример, допустим вы хотите вывести числа от 0 до 9 построчно.

Очевидно, что можно сделать так:

```
Console.WriteLine(0);
Console.WriteLine(1);
Console.WriteLine(2);
Console.WriteLine(3);
Console.WriteLine(4);
Console.WriteLine(5);
Console.WriteLine(6);
Console.WriteLine(7);
Console.WriteLine(8);
Console.WriteLine(9);
```

Результат конечно достигнут, но что делать если чисел не 10, а 10000?

Ок, попробуем обойтись совсем старыми средствами **(данный код строго демонстрационный, хоть он и работает, использовать его не надо нигде и никогда)**

```
//Объявляем и инициализируем счетчик
int i = 0; 
//метка позволяет вернуться на эту сроку кода во время выполнения
a: 
//Проверяем условие и решаем, будем ли выполнять действие
if (i < 10)
{
    //что-то делаем
    Console.WriteLine(i);
    //меняем значение счетчика
    i++;
    //возвращаемся к проверке условия
    goto a;
}
```

Цель достигнута? Безусловно. Но почему этот код плохой? Представьте что в вашей программе не одна метка, а пара десятков, запутаться какая для чего и когда именно на нее будет возврат проще простого. Читать такой код очень тяжело, искать ошибки еще тяжелее. Хотя надо отметить что на самом нижнем уровне оно именно так и работает, но у нас же язык высокого уровня, значит должны быть более простые и понятные человеку конструкции. И они есть, в первую очередь универсальный, во всех смыслах, цикл `while`:

```
//Объявляем и инициализируем счетчик
int j = 0;
//Проверяем условие и решаем, будем ли выполнять действие
while(j < 10)
{
    //что-то делаем
    Console.WriteLine(j);
    //меняем значение счетчика
    j++;
    //возвращаемся к проверке условия
}
```

От предыдущего кода отличается только отсутствием метки и ключевым словом `while` вместо `if`. Границы блока, который будет выполняться несколько раз, задают фигурные скобки. Хорошо? И да, и нет, потому что у нас все еще остается место потенциальной ошибки - это изменение счетчика. Оно должно происходить в самом конце повторяющегося блока, а условие выполнения находится в самом начале. Если кода в повторяющемся блоке много, то можно случайно забыть про необходимость поменять счетчик или изменить его не так как нужно и цикл превратится в вечный.

Последняя проблема решается с помощью цикла `for`:

```
//Объявляем и инициализируем счетчик,
//проверяем условие и решаем, будем ли выполнять действие
for(int k = 0; k < 10; k++)
{
    //что-то делаем
    Console.WriteLine(k);
    //возвращаемся к проверке условия
}
```

Как видите, и начальное значение счетчика, и условие, и правило изменения счетчика задаются в одной конструкции максимально близко друг к другу, что позволяет сразу заметить ошибку не бегая по всему коду цикла.

Для компилятора и CLR, которая будет выполнять ваш код, разницы между этими вариантами абсолютно никакой, но исходный код программы должен быть понятен человеку, который будет его читать и отлаживать. Поэтому в рассмотренном примере использование цикла 'for' предпочтительнее.

Теперь посмотрим что скрывается за конструкцией `foreach`. Некоторые вещи будут вам незнакомы, поэтому для начала сравните понятность полученного кода, а потом разберитесь с незнакомыми классами и методами с помощью [документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/).

И так, допустим у нас есть некоторая коллекция объектов, например чисел `List<int>`. Нам не важно какие там числа, в каком порядке, мы просто хотим вывести их все. Разумеется можно воспользоваться циклом `for` и доставать элементы из коллекции по их порядковому номеру.

```
var numberCollection = new List<int> {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

for (int m = 0; m < numberCollection.Count; m++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(numberCollection[m]);
}
```

Однако, далеко не все коллекции позволяют обращаться к своим элементам по порядковому номеру, т.к. этого номера может и не быть. А еще есть перечисления (`IEnumerable`, `IEnumerable<T>`), у которых даже своих элементов нет, они предоставляют избранные элементы какой-то другой коллекции или вообще генерируют их налету. Что делать? Воспользуемся перечислителем (`IEnumerator`, `IEnumerator<T>`) и циклом `while`:

```
//получаем перечислитель
using(var enumerator = numberCollection.GetEnumerator())
{
    //пока можем получить очередной элемент выполняем цикл
    while (enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        //выводим текущий элемент коллекции. на который указывает перечислитель
        Console.WriteLine(enumerator.Current);
    }
}
```

Цель достигнута? Да, но... для того, чтобы понять с чем мы вообще работаем, нужно найти в коде объявление нашей коллекции и посмотреть из каких элементов она состоит. В общем работает, но читать такое, мягко говоря, не комфортно. А если код не такой простой как в нашем примере, то вообще мрак.

Вот тут и понадобится цикл `foreach`:

```
foreach(int a in numberCollection)
{
    Console.WriteLine(a);
}
```

Не трудно заметить, что в таком варианте однозначно понятен и тип элементов, с которыми будем работать, и из какой они коллекции, и ни какого вспомогательного кода в явном виде не присутствует. Разумеется, как и в случае с циклом `for`, компилятор все равно развернет ваш `foreach` именно в ту, неудобную для чтения, конструкцию, да еще и с метками, вместо понятного `while`, но это проблемы компилятора, своей цели мы добились - код краток и понятен человеку.

Ну вот как-то так. Если кто-то может дополнить и/или найдет неточности, дайте знать в комментариях, внесу правки.

PS: Я в курсе, что конструкция под капотом `foreach` более забористая, но намерено не стал приводить полную развертку, т.к. считаю, что для понимания полезности `foreach` этого должно быть достаточно.

Comment: _"Но мы помним, нам не важен порядок"_ - что-то я не понял, зачем нам неважность порядка.

Comment: Сейчас попробую переформулировать или совсем уберу. Само написалось =)

Comment: Кстати, ещё можно что-то дополнить про то, что в for не только счётчик можно пихать.

Comment: @Qwertiy вот этого пока точно не надо =) Туда весь цикл запихнуть можно, но читать от этого легче не станет.

Comment: Ну подъём по дереву `for (var x = leaf; x != null; x = x.parent)` отлично на него ложится. Да и полно другого тоже, только навскидку не вспоминается.

Comment: @Qwertiy хм, действительно, еще не попадался такой вариант использования, хотя тоже по всякому с ним извращался. Надо запомнить, не то чтобы это сильно читабельнее классического `while`, но что-то в этом есть. Это, к стати, можно отдельным вопросом запилить, "А как еще можно использовать for" =)

Comment: А еще через foreach можно перебирать объекты из коллекций без строгой типизации. Что-то вроде  foreach(object a in Collection)

Comment: @Ivan это не менее строгая типизация, просто по базовому типу. Тоже самое можно сделать любым циклом. К слову, даже `var` не нарушает строгую типизацию. Единственная конструкция C# которая ее нарушает - тип `dynamic`.

Answer (score 4):

Это циклы. Они нужны для перебора элементов в некой коллекции(наборе элементов). Или для того что бы повторять некое действие N раз.

Форичем можно перебирать все что реализует интерфейс IEnumerable для перебора ВСЕХ элементов коллекции.

Пример использования:

```
int[] someArray = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}
foreach (int tempNumber in someArray)
{
    //здесь на каждом витке вызова цикла tempNumber 
    //будет равен следующему числу из набора. 
    //Сначала 1, потом 2, потом 3 и т.д.
}
```

приблизительно то же самое можно сделать при помощи for

```
for(int i=0; i<= someArray.Length; i+=1)
{
    var tempNumber = someArray[i];

    //результат тот же на каждом витке цикла. 
    //Только здесь я явно задаю tempNumber через 
    //присваивание и сам перебираю индексы массива 
    //которые записываю в "i"
}
```

for является более громоздкой конструкцией, но при этом дает больше возможностей. Например, можно перебирать не каждый элемент, а каждый 2й, третий, пятый, десятый. Или же задавать рамки что я буду рабоать с промежутком элементов от 15го до 30го в то время как в самой колекции элементов будет 150.

Так же for используется не только для колекций, а для того что бы сделать что-то N раз. Например, написать всю табличку умножения на 9.

```
for(int i=1; i<= 10; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine( $"{i} * 9 = {i*9}" );
}
```

Comment: `можно перебирать все что наследуется от интерфейса IEnumerable` не совсем верно :)

Comment: @tym32167 я не против любых правок если они сделают ответ более верным или понятным для нулевого уровня :)

Comment: Ладно, для нулевого уровня оставим так :)

Comment: Концептуально `for` от `foreach` отличается наличием входного условия перебора. Вот и всё что нужно знать.

Comment: @Rootware нулевому уровню эта формулировка многое обьяснит. :D

Answer (score 0):

Просто красивая таблица умножения: https://ideone.com/zff2Cw

```
using System;

public class Test
{
  public static void Main()
  {
    for (int q=0, d=5; q<10; q+=d)
    {
      for (int b=0; b<10; ++b)
      {
        for (int a=q; a<q+d; ++a)
          Console.Write("{0} * {1} = {2,2}   ", a, b, a*b);

        Console.WriteLine();
      }

      Console.WriteLine();
    }
  }
}
```

```
0 * 0 =  0   1 * 0 =  0   2 * 0 =  0   3 * 0 =  0   4 * 0 =  0   
0 * 1 =  0   1 * 1 =  1   2 * 1 =  2   3 * 1 =  3   4 * 1 =  4   
0 * 2 =  0   1 * 2 =  2   2 * 2 =  4   3 * 2 =  6   4 * 2 =  8   
0 * 3 =  0   1 * 3 =  3   2 * 3 =  6   3 * 3 =  9   4 * 3 = 12   
0 * 4 =  0   1 * 4 =  4   2 * 4 =  8   3 * 4 = 12   4 * 4 = 16   
0 * 5 =  0   1 * 5 =  5   2 * 5 = 10   3 * 5 = 15   4 * 5 = 20   
0 * 6 =  0   1 * 6 =  6   2 * 6 = 12   3 * 6 = 18   4 * 6 = 24   
0 * 7 =  0   1 * 7 =  7   2 * 7 = 14   3 * 7 = 21   4 * 7 = 28   
0 * 8 =  0   1 * 8 =  8   2 * 8 = 16   3 * 8 = 24   4 * 8 = 32   
0 * 9 =  0   1 * 9 =  9   2 * 9 = 18   3 * 9 = 27   4 * 9 = 36   

5 * 0 =  0   6 * 0 =  0   7 * 0 =  0   8 * 0 =  0   9 * 0 =  0   
5 * 1 =  5   6 * 1 =  6   7 * 1 =  7   8 * 1 =  8   9 * 1 =  9   
5 * 2 = 10   6 * 2 = 12   7 * 2 = 14   8 * 2 = 16   9 * 2 = 18   
5 * 3 = 15   6 * 3 = 18   7 * 3 = 21   8 * 3 = 24   9 * 3 = 27   
5 * 4 = 20   6 * 4 = 24   7 * 4 = 28   8 * 4 = 32   9 * 4 = 36   
5 * 5 = 25   6 * 5 = 30   7 * 5 = 35   8 * 5 = 40   9 * 5 = 45   
5 * 6 = 30   6 * 6 = 36   7 * 6 = 42   8 * 6 = 48   9 * 6 = 54   
5 * 7 = 35   6 * 7 = 42   7 * 7 = 49   8 * 7 = 56   9 * 7 = 63   
5 * 8 = 40   6 * 8 = 48   7 * 8 = 56   8 * 8 = 64   9 * 8 = 72   
5 * 9 = 45   6 * 9 = 54   7 * 9 = 63   8 * 9 = 72   9 * 9 = 81
```